# Connecting Tomcat to standalone Artemis Broker via JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jndi, activemq-artemis

I want to define a jms ConnectionFactory as global resource in tomcat server.xml to connect my webapps to standalone Artemis server.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any official or clean manual for such a common use case that describes required libraries and configurations.

Can somebody show me an example?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1182

Comment: Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any native Artemis based solution. Artemis server is ActiveMQ client compatible. So we can follow ActiveMQ manual for this purpose.

- Add ActiveMQ client libraries to $CATALINA_HOME/lib

  - geronimo-jms_2.0_spec-1.0-alpha-2.jar
  - activemq-client-5.14.3.jar
  - geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
  - hawtbuf-1.11.jar
  - slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
- Add global resource to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml

  ```
  <Resource auth="Container"
      name="jms/ConnectionFactory"
      type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
      factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
      brokerURL="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"
      brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker"/>
  ```
- Add resource link to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml

  ```
  <ResourceLink name="/ConnectionFactory" 
      global="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
      type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
  ```
- Look up connection factory in app context

  ```
  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
      <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/ConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
  </bean>
  ```